# SwiftUI: ForEach using shared / nested data -- UI won't update after modification

Tags: swiftui

I have a class that can optionally contain an array of its own type. I've created SwiftUI view to display this data, nesting a new SwiftUI view for each subitem encountered in a ForEach. This all works fine until the data needs to be modified. Changes initiated from nested views don't propagate and update the UI.

Example class:

```swift
class Foo: Equatable, Hashable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var subFoos: [Foo]?
    
    init(name: String, subFoos: [Foo]? = nil) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.name = name
        self.subFoos = subFoos
    }
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        return hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

SwiftUI example:

```swift
struct FooContainer: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: ViewModel? = nil, foo: Foo, nestingLevel: Int = 0) {
        let viewModel = viewModel ?? ViewModel(foo: foo)
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if let foo = viewModel.foo {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(foo.name)
                        Text(foo.id.uuidString)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button {
                        viewModel.addSubFoo()
                    } label: {
                        Text("+")
                            .font(.title)
                    }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
                    
                    Button {
                        viewModel.deleteFoo()
                    } label: {
                        Text("-")
                            .font(.title)
                    }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 64)
                .background(Color.random)
                
                VStack(spacing: 8) {
                    ForEach(foo.subFoos ?? [], id: \.self) { subFoo in
                        FooContainer(foo: subFoo)
                            .padding(.leading, 32)
                    }
                }
            }
            .animation(.default, value: foo.subFoos)
        }
    }
}

extension FooContainer {
    @MainActor
    final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var foo: Foo?
        
        init(foo: Foo) {
            self.foo = foo
        }
        
        func addSubFoo() {
            let newFoo = Foo(name: "Added Foo")
            if foo?.subFoos == nil {
                foo?.subFoos = [newFoo]
            } else {
                foo?.subFoos?.append(newFoo)
            }
            
            // this will force a redraw and allow an added row to appear
            // without it the UI won't be updated
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
        
        func deleteFoo() {
            foo = nil
            // this will force a redraw and allow a row to be deleted visually
            // without it the UI won't be updated -- note: will never animate
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let nestedFoos = Foo(
            name: "Root Foo",
            subFoos: [
                Foo(
                    name: "SubFoo 1",
                    subFoos: [
                        Foo(
                            name: "SubFoo 2",
                            subFoos: nil
                        )
                    ]
                )
            ]
        )
        
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            FooContainer (
                foo: nestedFoos
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I can force the UI to update using `objectWillChange.send()` but that feels inefficient, pretty inelegant and doesn't end up animating in some cases. I feel like bindings are the solution here, specifically the introduction of bindings for list elements in Swift 5.5. I've tried making the foo in the ViewModel a binding which works fine until I have to pass one of the nested subFoos on init to one of the nested FooContainer views. I've tried all manner of syntax to pass a binding for a subFoo value in the subFoos array of an already bound object and have failed miserably.

Any help or alternate concepts would be appreciated!

Comment: All `ObservedObject`s have to be wrapped using the appropriate wrapper at every level. `@StateObject` to initialize, `@ObservedObject` to pass down and `@EnvironmentObject` to inject. You also need to wrap its variables with `@Published` when you want to trigger a redraw.

Comment: Change your model to a struct instead of a class and it'll all basically work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies. Using a struct instead of a class does remove the necessity of calling objectWillChange.send(). I had originally switched to a class so that I could reference a parent Foo in each subFoo (which works great) in the hopes that calling parent?.subFoos?.remove(someSubFoo) on someSubFoo would result in an animation on deletion. It doesn't unfortunately. I suppose that's really the issue at the end of the day... I'm unable to animate a deletion.

Comment: Ask a new question about the deletion animation and post your current working code.

Comment: With structs you can use arrays of ids to model the child relationships

Comment: View struct is the view model already, StateObject is for something else